# How can I mock service with complex request in Mockito and JUint?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have an interface:

```
public interface SenderService {
    String send(long amount);
}
```

And I have an implementation of this interface:

```
public class SenderServiceAdapter implements SenderService {

    private final ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService;

    public SenderServiceAdapter(ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService) {
        this.thirdPartyService = thirdPartyService;
    }

    @Override
    public String send(long amount) {

        ThirdPartyRequest thirdPartyRequest = new ThirdPartyRequest();

        thirdPartyRequest.setAmount(amount);
        thirdPartyRequest.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        thirdPartyRequest.setDate(new Date());

        ThirdPartyResponse thirdPartyResponse = thirdPartyService.send(thirdPartyRequest);

        String status = thirdPartyResponse.getStatus();

        if (status.equals("Error")) throw new RuntimeException("blablabla");

        return thirdPartyResponse.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Now I want to write `Unit test` for this service. I need to mock `thirdPartyService's` method `send`. But I don't understand how.

```
public class SenderServiceAdapterTest {

    private ThirdPartyService thirdPartyService;
    private SenderService senderService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        thirdPartyService = Mockito.mock(ThirdPartyService.class);
        senderService = new SenderServiceAdapter(thirdPartyService);
    }

    @Test
    public void send() {

        when(thirdPartyService.send(new ThirdPartyRequest())).thenReturn(new ThirdPartyResponse());

        String message = senderService.send(100L);

    }
}
```

The `ThirdPartyRequest` creates in `SenderServiceAdapter`. How can I mock it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
doReturn(new ThirdPartyResponse()).when(thirdPartyService).send(any(ThirdPartyRequest.class));
```

Also by looking your code, you will need to set something in the response, so you will have to do this:

```
ThirdPartyResponse response = new ThirdPartyResponse(); //or mock
response.setStatus(...);
response.setMessage(...);
doReturn(response).when(thirdPartyService).send(any(ThirdPartyRequest.class));
```